# A generic websocket client in python using websockets library and asyncio

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I am trying to hack together a basic generic client interface from the websockets documentation. I'm using [this](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#both) example as a starting point.

The following code sends 10 strings in a loop but either none of them are coming back from the echo server, or they are not reaching the `consumer` method

I have tried replacing a method in the code below with the following ...

```
async def consumer_handler(self, websocket, path):
    try:
        logger.debug("Beginning consumer")
        while True:
            try:
                message = await asyncio.wait_for(websocket.recv(), timeout=1.0)
                logger.debug(f"Recieved message {message}")
                await self.consumer(message)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                logger.debug("Consumer timeout")
    finally:
        logger.debug("Ended consumer")
```

... but that doesnt make any difference. Further, neither the "Consumer Timeout" or "Received Message" logs are printed, so it seems like this loop is not running after the producer_handler is started (consumer_handler does get started as the "Beginning consumer" string is logged). I also note that the "Ended consumer" and "Ended producer" strings are never logged.

```
import asyncio
import websockets
from queue import Queue
import logging
from functools import partial
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import time

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)-15s %(threadName)s %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger("")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

class Application:
    def __init__(self):
        self.executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8)

    def getExecutor(self):
        return self.executor
    
    def close(self):
        self.executor.shutdown()


class Client:
    
    ###########################################################################
    # Business Logic
        
    def sendMessage(self, message):
        self.messageQueue.put(message)
    
    async def consumer(self, message):
        logger.debug(f"Consumed message {message}")
        
    ###########################################################################
    
    ###########################################################################
    # General
    
    def __init__(self, app):
        
        self.app = app
        
        self.messageQueue = Queue()
        self.ws = None
    
    async def producer(self):
        logger.debug("In producer")
        return self.messageQueue.get()
    
    
    def connect(self, uri):
        self.app.getExecutor().submit(partial(self._connect, uri))
    
    def _connect(self, uri):
        asyncio.run(self.__connect(uri), debug=True)
    
    async def __connect(self, uri):
        logger.debug("Connecting")
        self.ws = await websockets.connect(uri)  
        await self.handler(self.ws, uri)
    
    def close(self):
         self.app.getExecutor().submit(self._close)
         
    def _close(self):
        asyncio.run(self.__close(), debug=True)
    
    async def __close(self):
        logger.debug("Ending client")
        await self.ws.close()

    #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    # remaining part of class is from 
    # https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#both

    async def consumer_handler(self, websocket, path):
        try:
            logger.debug("Beginning consumer")
            async for message in websocket:
                logger.debug(f"Recieved message {message}")
                await self.consumer(message)
        finally:
            logger.debug("Ended consumer")

            
    async def producer_handler(self, websocket, path):
        logger.debug("Beginning producer")
        try:
            while True:
                message = await self.producer()
                await websocket.send(message)
                logger.debug(f"Sent: {message}")
        finally:
            logger.debug("Ended producer")
            
    
    async def handler(self, websocket, path):
        consumer_task = asyncio.create_task(
            self.consumer_handler(websocket, path))
        producer_task = asyncio.create_task(
            self.producer_handler(websocket, path))
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
            [consumer_task, producer_task],
            return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED,
        )
        for task in pending:
            task.cancel()
        
def main():
    
    ADDRESS = "ws://echo.websocket.org/"
    
    logger.debug("Beginning client")
    
    app = Application()
    try:
        client = Client(app)
        try:
            client.connect(ADDRESS)
        
            time.sleep(2)
            
            for i in range(10):
                client.sendMessage(f"Hello {i}")
                time.sleep(0.5)
            
            time.sleep(3)
            
        finally:
            client.close()
            time.sleep(2)
    finally:
        app.close()

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the `producer_handler` task was not giving up the event loop for some reason despite the wait on a `websocket.send` (which I think is the expectation and I suspect that this will be a problem for anyone following the documentation). To overcome this, I added a `asyncio.sleep` call which does give up the event loop, allowing the `consumer_handler` to be reentered.

```
async def producer_handler(self, websocket, path):
    logger.debug("Beginning producer")
    try:
        while True:
            message = await self.producer()
            await websocket.send(message)
            logger.debug(f"Sent: {message}")
            
            # The fix! This gives up the event loop so that consumer_handler can be revisited
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
    finally:
        logger.debug("Ended producer")
```

The fact that the handlers were not shutting down correctly was also an issue with threading. I changed the `__connect` and `close` functions to

```
async def __connect(self, uri):
    self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    logger.debug("Connecting")
    self.ws = await websockets.connect(uri)  
    await self.handler(self.ws, uri)

def close(self):
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.__close(), self.loop)
```

and now everything is as expected.

The complete, working example....

```
import asyncio
import websockets
from queue import Queue
import logging
from functools import partial
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import time

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)-15s %(threadName)s %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger("")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

class Application:
    def __init__(self):
        self.executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8)

    def getExecutor(self):
        return self.executor
    
    def close(self):
        self.executor.shutdown()


class Client:
    
    ###########################################################################
    # Business Logic
        
    def sendMessage(self, message):
        self.messageQueue.put(message)
    
    async def consumer(self, message):
        logger.debug(f"Consumed message {message}")
        
    ###########################################################################
    
    ###########################################################################
    # General
    
    def __init__(self, app):
        
        self.app = app
        
        self.messageQueue = Queue()
        self.ws = None
    
    async def producer(self):
        logger.debug("In producer")
        return self.messageQueue.get()
    
    
    def connect(self, uri):
        self.app.getExecutor().submit(partial(self._connect, uri))
    
    def _connect(self, uri):
        asyncio.run(self.__connect(uri), debug=True)
    
    async def __connect(self, uri):
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        logger.debug("Connecting")
        self.ws = await websockets.connect(uri)  
        await self.handler(self.ws, uri)
    
    def close(self):
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.__close(), self.loop)

    async def __close(self):
        logger.debug("Ending client")
        await self.ws.close()

    #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    # remaining part of class is from 
    # https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#both

    async def consumer_handler(self, websocket, path):
        try:
            logger.debug("Beginning consumer")
            async for message in websocket:
                logger.debug(f"Recieved message {message}")
                await self.consumer(message)
        finally:
            logger.debug("Ended consumer")

            
    async def producer_handler(self, websocket, path):
        logger.debug("Beginning producer")
        try:
            while True:
                message = await self.producer()
                await websocket.send(message)
                logger.debug(f"Sent: {message}")
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
        finally:
            logger.debug("Ended producer")
            

    async def handler(self, websocket, path):
        '''This simply schedules the sequential execution of the producer_task
        and consumer_task. It does NOT run them in parallel!'''
        producer_task = asyncio.ensure_future(
            self.producer_handler(websocket, path))
        consumer_task = asyncio.ensure_future(
            self.consumer_handler(websocket, path))
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
            [consumer_task, producer_task],
            return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED,
        )
        for task in pending:
            task.cancel()

def main():
    
    ADDRESS = "ws://echo.websocket.org/"
    
    logger.debug("Beginning client")
    
    app = Application()
    try:
        client = Client(app)
        try:
            client.connect(ADDRESS)
        
            time.sleep(2)
            
            for i in range(10):
                client.sendMessage(f"Hello {i}")
                time.sleep(0.5)

            time.sleep(1)
            
        finally:
            client.close()
            time.sleep(3)
    finally:
        app.close()

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```